# Juntar ou separar colunas repetidas em tabelas diferentes

Tags: mysql, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Criei uma tabela `tbl_users`.

Mas tenho `Profissionais` e `Empresas` que muitas colunas são as mesmas. Seria interessante utilizar na mesma tabela, ou é melhor separar?

Comment: Sua pergunta estão muita vaga,  ninguém vai conseguir te ajudar. Coloque as tabelas com todos os atributos para que possamos te ajudar.

Comment: Um excelente conteúdo para ser lido sobre esse assunto [DEV MEDIA](https://www.devmedia.com.br/modelo-entidade-relacionamento-mer-e-diagrama-entidade-relacionamento-der/14332). Tem que avaliar a quantidade de colunas que são iguais. Supondo que cada tabela tenha 10 colunas e destas 10 umas 7 são iguais, eu deixaria junto.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 2):

Mesmo com a pergunta não tendo informações suficientes para dar uma resposta certeira, tem algo que vale sempre: normalize a informação.

Modelar é definir onde vai cada coisa.

Podemos falar em [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) aqui. Se as informações por acaso são as mesmas, mas não há relação direta entre elas então está tudo certo. Se é essencialmente a mesma informação então deve-se pensar em ter uma separação da parte que se repete. Pelo menos em modelo lógico.

Em modelo físico há casos de otimização que acabam sendo mais interessante ter o modelo parcialmente repetido para evitar relacionamentos desnecessários. É só por questão de performance.

Não é a repetição que importa é a funcionalidade que as colunas possuem. Não é a quantidade de colunas repetidas que importa.

Vamos dizer que tenha colunas de endereço em cada tabela. Vale a pena ter o endereço separado? Se for só pra organizar a tabela não vale. Se deseja ter endereços como uma entidade distinta que pode ser usada em mais de uma entidade na mesma tabela ou em tabelas diferentes, aí faz sentido ter algo assim.

Na verdade modelagem tem que partir de uma conceituação correta que vem antes de resolver essas coisas. Precisa estudar ontologia, taxinomia e até semiótica. Por exemplo do que já mudaria entendendo essas coisas e não usar `tbl_` nos nomes de tabelas. Isso sim é redundância.